# Function in .then() not getting called

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am using a Promise in a function to ensure the dynamic element loaded by the function is available when I try to fix some CSS styles. But fixStyling is never executed. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
const fixStyling = function(){
   console.log('change style');
   let surveyBody = document.querySelector('.survey-page-body');
   surveyBody.style.marginTop = "-60px";
}


function loadSM() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       (function(t,e,s,n){var o,a,c;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(n)||(o=e.getElementsByTagName(s),a=o[o.length-1],c=e.createElement(s),c.type="text/javascript",c.async=!0,c.id=n,c.src="https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/tRaiETqnLgj758hTBazgd1CDe7_2F_2F4snTovolmrpjpv7u54RGrphPxAqunQp3_2FUPz.js",a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");
   });
}

loadSM().then(fixStyling());
```

Comment: .then takes a callback. You are passing in a called function. Try removing the ().

Comment: Great capture @Invizi perhaps pointing to where it needs to be removed from would've helped him/her, such as Try removing the () and make it `loadSM().then(fixStyling);`. Just my bit of help to make your answer complete. Peace!!

Comment: Thanks @Invizi and @Avinash! I had actually tried that too and it still skips fixStyling, which makes me wonder if the Promise is the problem but I am using resolve so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Invizi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10038648/invizi) mentioned,
the function takes a callback.

So either like this - `loadSM().then(fixStyling);`
Or like this - `loadSM().then(() => fixStyling());`

Comment: I actually tried with a callback too and it doesn't work either. I can see in DevTools how loadSM() is executed as expected but fixStyling is skipped for some reason. Unfortunately, ES6 is not compatible with browsers used internally at my company so can't use the arrow fn.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code wasnt working was because of the promise you made in loadSM(). You never resolved or rejected the promise, so next was never triggered.

```js
function fixStyling() {
  console.log('change style');
  let surveyBody = document.querySelector('.survey-page-body');
  surveyBody.style.marginTop = "-60px";
}


function loadSM() {
  return Promise.resolve(
    (function(t, e, s, n) {
      var o, a, c;
      t.SMCX = t.SMCX || [], e.getElementById(n) || (o = e.getElementsByTagName(s), a = o[o.length - 1], c = e.createElement(s), c.type = "text/javascript", c.async = !0, c.id = n, c.src = "https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/tRaiETqnLgj758hTBazgd1CDe7_2F_2F4snTovolmrpjpv7u54RGrphPxAqunQp3_2FUPz.js", a.parentNode.insertBefore(c, a))
    })(window, document, "script", "smcx-sdk"));
}

loadSM().then(fixStyling);
```

Comment: This worked - thank you!